# Убрать switch размером с гору Эверест

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, есть `switch` длиной с Эверест, как бы вы избавились от него, кроме как записывать это в `Dictionary`?

```
        switch (currencyLeft)
        {
            case "BTC":
                return 0.001m;
            case "BCH":
            case "ETH":
            case "FCT":
            case "NEO":
            case "UBTC":
            case "XEM":
            case "ZEC":
                return 0.01m;
            case "MCO":
            case "QTUM":
            case "REP":
            case "STX":
            case "VET":
                return 0.1m;
            case "ETC":
            case "DASH":
            case "LTC":
            case "XLM":
            case "XRP":
            case "XMR":
                return 0.5m;
            case "GAT":
                return 8m;
            case "BMC":
            case "DENT":
            case "DRG":
            case "ETN":
            case "FDX":
            case "FLIXX":
            case "FSN":
            case "GZE":
            case "IND":
            case "IXT":
            case "MTN":
            case "OAX":
            case "ONG":
            case "QASH":
            case "RKT":
            case "SAL":
            case "SER":
            case "SNIP":
            case "SPHTX":
            case "STAC":
            case "STORJ":
            case "STU":
            case "TPT":
            case "TRX":
            case "VZT":
                return 1m;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported symbol");
        }
```

UPD: сам `switch` и так находится в приватном методе, который возвращает `decimal` и принимает `string`. Задача в том, чтобы этот код (логику, если так можно "это" назвать) как-то упростить (уменьшить), если это возможно, но не словарем.

Comment: Словарь это единственное что в голову приходит. Такое непотребство точно не стоит оставлять.

Comment: А кстати, со словарем это у вас хорошая идея.

Comment: Можно преобразовать в число bigint. c# по нему двоичный поиск сделает. Хотя... для такого свича скорее всего тоже двоичный поиск будет.

Comment: @Bulson, ага, большой свич станет большим инициализатором словаря. Отличная идея)

Comment: @free_ze, да в этом есть недостаток, но что тогда вы со своей стороны предложите?

Comment: @Bulson, я бы добавил пустые строки после `return` (чтобы зрительно выделить блоки), а саму конструкцию упаковал бы в приватный метод и оставил в покое.

Comment: @nick_n_a, любой поиск и тем более конвертация будет хуже свича. Для чтения в том числе.

Comment: @free_ze c учетом голосов за словарь ваш вариант пока проигрывает. Подождем других возможных вариантов и голосов.

Comment: еще вариант база данных, чтобы не инициализировать каждый раз словарь (если вдруг еще будет расти)

Comment: @Bulson, главное, что со мной уже согласились вы)

Comment: @Shpunder, чтобы не инициализировать словарь каждый раз, его можно инициализировать один раз и потом использовать всю жизнь)

Comment: Мне нравится и словарь и вынести в отдельную функцию, на самом деле сам код плох если он будет частью какой-то функции и внутри неё идти inline, если же он будет в отдельной своей функции, то почему бы и нет, кстати инициализатор словаря будет не более красиво выглядеть, а может даже и менее, там придётся дубликаты значений заводить, а если значение поменяется все дубликаты придётся поменять. Конечно можно их константами задать, перед определением словаря, но это ещё больше усложнит код, и сделает менее понятным. Так что я за отдельную функцию. Но мой лайк стоит и на словаре тоже.

Comment: И кстати с точки зрения инкапсуляции и красоты кода не особо будет важна реализация, главное что на поверхности будет просто функция принимающая строку а возвращающая число.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хардкод значений и курсов в коде - это нехорошо.

Положите все это в CSV / JSON / базу данных. Т.е. в любое хранилище, кроме кода. Поднимайте из хранилища по первому обращению и десериализуйте в `Dictionary<string, decimal>`.

Answer (score 3):

В switch – данные. Данные, по возможности, отделяют от логики 
программы. Раз уж данных много, можно хранить их в файлах,
в настройках программы или в базе. Вот подходящий ответ[Как хранить данные в программе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593907/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5/593913#593913)