# Как правильно организовать логику приложения WPF С#

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал оболочку к программе.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Собрался переходить к логике.
 Программа состоит из поля для ввода (textBox), кнопки, и (DataGrid) разделённого на три категории (Сумма, Результат, Дата) вопрос в следующем. Как организовать логику программы для хранения данных. Так что бы данные распределялись по таблице. Через базу данных или через сохранение в файл или может есть ещё какие способы. Как правильно организовать этот процесс?

Comment: Где требуется, там и храните: можете в базе, можете в файле, если требуется можете хранить в облаке или печатать на бумаге. Если бы был один правильный способ, то разных способов бы не было.

Comment: @default locale Имеется ввиду правильно для создания DeskTop приложений. Как это вообще делается в конторах там.

Comment: @default locale С точки зрения программиста.

Comment: В конторах делают по ситуации, кто во что горазд. Общего ответа нет, да и быть не может. Подумайте о том, как будет осуществляться доступ к данным: будут они храниться на одной машине (файлы, локальная БД), в закрытой сети (сервер БД), глобально через интернет (БД + сервисы). Вариантов очень много, чтобы знать точно нужно их перепробовать.

Comment: Рекомендую [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/)

Comment: А почитайте вот этот вопрос, там умные люди расписали общие подходы для простого случая: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593907/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5

Comment: @Bulson  Спасибо за ответы! Думаю воспользуюсь  LiteDB.

Comment: @default locale  Спасибо за ответ!